# IP Address in internal DNS needed for IIS site hosting

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a server that hosts IIS websites. Each website has a different IP. In order for the IP to show up for selection in IIS, I've bound each IP to the network interface (which now has multiple IPs instead of just the one server IP). The server does not have multiple NICs, so they all need to go on the single NIC present.

My question: Internal DNS automatically registers all IP addresses assigned to the NIC. However, the server is only supposed to respond (as a server) on the primary IP. Can I safely remove DNS registration from the NIC altogether and only add the single primary IP to internal DNS, while still keeping IIS working properly with its websites on other IPs?

Answer (score 0):

DNS registration just means that it dynamically registers with DNS. If you don't want the primary hostname of the machine registering in DNS with all of those IP's then yes, remove it and maintain the DNS manually.  At the end of the day you need to make sure you have DNS entries for all of your sites on their relative IP addresses, and then have the bindings set up in IIS so that it knows where to find the sites.

Comment: If those other IPs aren't in DNS, would that break the IIS sites though? (Again, i'm talking internal DNS pointing to the server, not external DNS for URLs).

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your issue, You are using multipal IPs with single NIC, to host multipal Websites at IIS and you would like to remove all IPs from NIC and like to use an Single IP. If   i am in right direction, you have to need creating associates records at your DNS and perform binding at your IIS. You should have a look at [HERE](http://support.orcsweb.com/KB/a324/create-an-iis-75-web-site-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) & [HERE](http://support.orcsweb.com/KB/a308/iis-site-bindings.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

As squillman stated, you can remove the DNS entries on the DNS servers and set the server not to automatically register the other IP addresses. This will not stop the server from responding to any type requests on the other IP Addresses though.

If you aren't using any SSL connections, you could look at using host headers and using a single IP address for all the websites..